# В VS Code при использовании Emmet не срабатывают подсказки значений, если значение уже было подставлено Emmet'ом по-умолчанию

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, emmet

[image: Ввожу букву "p"]

1. Ввожу символ "p" - получаю "position: relative;"
2. Автоматически выделяется relative.
3. Ввожу символ "а", и при этом подсказка не появляется. "r" - подсказка тоже не появляется.
4. Стоит сместить курсор влево или вправо на один символ стрелкой на клавиатуре, а потом обратно, и ввести нужный символ, как подсказки вновь появляются.

И такая ситуация происходит везде, во всех парах "свойство - значение", где значение подставил сам Emmet.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? У неё есть решение?

- Отключение плагинов не помогло.
- Переустановка vc code не помогла.

Comment: Я привык писать posa, и он предлагает position: absolute, попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо. Да, есть такая возможность. Просто эта проблема намного шире. Например, если вставляю тег h2, нажимая tab. А потом ввести class, то между кавычек class="" нет автоматического подсказки классов при вводе символа. Хотя класс уже есть в css. При этом, опять же, если сместить курсор влево-вправо, то подсказка при вводе символа появляется.